# Importing json data using D3.json function

Tags: json, d3.js

I am currently trying to customize an example such as this ... http://bl.ocks.org/1377729 to take json data using the D3.json function.

At the moment I have been trying to do this:

```
     d3.json("http:", function(json) { 

     var nodes = [];
     var labelAnchors = [];
```

here i have tried to import the function, but it doesnt do anything

```
     for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {


            var node = json;
            nodes.push(node);
            labelAnchors.push({
                node : node
            });
            labelAnchors.push({
                node : node
            });
        };
```

I have also tried to put the function into the .text function

```
     anchorNode.append("svg:text")
            .text(function(d, i) {return i % 2 == 0 ? "" : d.node.json  })
            .style("fill", "#555")
            .style("font-family", "Arial")
            .style("font-size", 12);
```

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong please!

Comment: Your json url doesn't appear complete.

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#wiki-d3_json

Comment: Hi @nautat i purposely missed that part out .. is there anything else that is wrong?

Comment: Can you share what your json data structure looks like? From the example you cited, you can see that nodes, and labelAnchors are arrays (length 30) of objects. They node object looks like: { label: "node0" } and forms the nodes array. The object that forms the labelAnchors array looks like: { node: { label: "node0" } }.

Comment: My json data structure looks like this.. [{"Name":"Jake","id":16}].. Although I believe i will need to change the length parameters to maybe json.length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First build the nodes array and labelAnchors array by stepping through your json array.

```
   for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
     var node = json[i];
     nodes.push(node);
     labelAnchors.push({
       node : node
     });
     labelAnchors.push({
       node : node
     });
   };
```

The example relies on having objects with a key called `label`, while in your case that key is called `Name`. So you would need to adjust the example code to something like:

```
anchorNode.append("svg:text")
    .text(function(d, i) {
      return i % 2 == 0 ? "" : d.node.Name;
    })
    .style("fill", "#555")
    .style("font-family", "Arial")
    .style("font-size", 12);
```