# Uncaught error reading in json data to d3 force-directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am having a similar problem to the one described [here](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/13127734/), but the solution offered there doesn't seem to work for me. I am trying to create a force-directed graph with force-based label placement using my own json data. I'm running into an unspecified uncaught javascript error at the point of reading in my data. My data is in the following format:

```
{"nodes": [{"name": Bob, "id": 1}, {"name": Suzy, "id": 2}],
 "links": [{"source": 1, "target":2}]}
```

My script is below. Any insight would be enormously helpful!

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      var w = 960, h = 500;

      var labelDistance = 0;

      var vis = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg").attr("width", w).attr("height", h);

      var nodes = [];
      var labelAnchors = [];
      var labelAnchorLinks = [];
      var links = [];

    d3.json("data.json", function(error, graph) {
        if (error) throw error;

 
   for (var i = 0; i < graph.nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = graph.nodes[i];
     nodes.push(node);
     labelAnchors.push({
       node : node
     });
     labelAnchors.push({
       node : node
     });
   }
    
    graph.links.forEach(function(link, i) {

      links.push({
        source: link.source,
        target: link.target,
        weight: Math.random()
      });
      labelAnchorLinks.push({
        source: link.source * 2,
        target: link.target * 2 + 1,
        weight: 1
      });
    });

      var force = d3.layout.force().size([w, h]).nodes(nodes).links(links).gravity(1).linkDistance(50).charge(-3000).linkStrength(function(x) {
        return x.weight * 10
      });


      force.start();

      var force2 = d3.layout.force().nodes(labelAnchors).links(labelAnchorLinks).gravity(0).linkDistance(0).linkStrength(8).charge(-100).size([w, h]);
      force2.start();

      var link = vis.selectAll("line.link").data(links).enter().append("svg:line").attr("class", "link").style("stroke", "#CCC");

      var node = vis.selectAll("g.node").data(force.nodes()).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "node");
      node.append("svg:circle").attr("r", 5).style("fill", "#555").style("stroke", "#FFF").style("stroke-width", 3);
      node.call(force.drag);


      var anchorLink = vis.selectAll("line.anchorLink").data(labelAnchorLinks)//.enter().append("svg:line").attr("class", "anchorLink").style("stroke", "#999");

      var anchorNode = vis.selectAll("g.anchorNode").data(force2.nodes()).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "anchorNode");
      anchorNode.append("svg:circle").attr("r", 0).style("fill", "#FFF");
        anchorNode.append("svg:text").text(function(d, i) {
        return i % 2 == 0 ? "" : d.node.label
      }).style("fill", "#555").style("font-family", "Arial").style("font-size", 12);

      var updateLink = function() {
        this.attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        }).attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        }).attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        }).attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });

      }

      var updateNode = function() {
        this.attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });

      }


      force.on("tick", function() {

        force2.start();

        node.call(updateNode);

        anchorNode.each(function(d, i) {
          if(i % 2 == 0) {
            d.x = d.node.x;
            d.y = d.node.y;
          } else {
            var b = this.childNodes[1].getBBox();

            var diffX = d.x - d.node.x;
            var diffY = d.y - d.node.y;

            var dist = Math.sqrt(diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY);

            var shiftX = b.width * (diffX - dist) / (dist * 2);
            shiftX = Math.max(-b.width, Math.min(0, shiftX));
            var shiftY = 5;
            this.childNodes[1].setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + shiftX + "," + shiftY + ")");
          }
        });


        anchorNode.call(updateNode);

        link.call(updateLink);
        anchorLink.call(updateLink);

  });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: You need a path to a `.json` file instead of `/data/` in your `d3.json` call.

Comment: Thanks, but that's actually a stand-in for the path to a hosted data file, and that path works just fine with a simpler force-directed d3 script. I think the script is tripping up elsewhere. I have edited my initial question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read a file without specifying a correct path to your file system or to an external resource.

That means that you have to swap this line:

```
d3.json("/data/", function(error, graph) {
```

With something like:

```
d3.json("./data.json", function(error, graph) {
```

Or:

```
d3.json("http://www.somesite.com/data.json", function(error, graph) {
```

Also, make sure you are running a local server on your machine otherwise that call will fail.

Comment: Thanks, but that's actually a stand-in for the path to a hosted data file, and that path works just fine with a simpler force-directed d3 script. I think the script is tripping up elsewhere. I have edited my initial question to avoid confusion.